# Scrape data form ClickTracking

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrap the data from a website but I encountered a small problem which I do not have the smallest idea how to solve. ( my first scraping tool , using beautifulsoup and requests )
I need the telephone number on the right "07xx xxx xxx"

When I firstly open the page and request it, I get this :
[image]

The thing is that I need the telephone number but it will not show until I press "Arata telefon" , is there a way how I can take this info out ?

Here is the page itself :
[Link](http://olx.ro/oferta/chirie-zona-camine-hasdeu-fac-medicina-apartament-2-camere-78-mp-ID6rQD4.html#67aa7e6209)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the ID from the url  i.e `6rqd4` to  http://olx.ro/ajax/misc/contact/phone:

```
In [22]: import requests

In [23]: requests.get("http://olx.ro/ajax/misc/contact/phone/6rqd4").json()
Out[23]: {'value': '0787 636 258'}
```

So if you have lots of urls you have scraped, you can extract the ID with a regex:

```
In [30]: import requests

In [31]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [32]: import re

In [33]: patt = re.compile("ID(\w+)\.html")

In [34]: url = "http://olx.ro/oferta/chirie-zona-camine-hasdeu-fac-medicina-apartament-2-camere-78-mp-ID6rQD4.html#"

In [35]: requests.get("http://olx.ro/ajax/misc/contact/phone/{}".format(patt.search(url).group(1))).json()
Out[35]: {'value': '0787 636 258'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing is that I want to scrape and make a database and I need all the telephone numbers not a specific one :(

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. I took fresh offer: https://www.olx.ro/ajax/misc/contact/phone/au6zd/ and got only 0000000